# PHP no imprime arreglo JSON

Tags: php, json

Hola chicos necesito de su colaboración en un modulo php que estoy construyendo, resulta que quiero imprimir un listado de ciudades en JSON pero cuando lo hago no me imprime nada, no sé que pueda estar pasando: este es mi código:

```
<?php

require "../model/Ciudad.php";

$_POST = $_GET;

function ListaCiudades(){
    $ciudad = new Ciudad();
    $ciudades = $ciudad->Select_Ciudaddes();
    $array_return = array();

    if($ciudades != null){
        foreach ($ciudades as $ciudad) {

            $arr = array("id_ciudad" => $ciudad['PK_ID_CIUDAD'], 
                        "nombre" => $ciudad['NOMBRE'], );
            array_push($array_return, $arr);
        }
    }

    return $array_return;
    // var_dump(json_encode($array_return, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}

/*Identificación del típo de consulta a realizar*/
if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){
    if($_POST['tipo'] == 'consulta'){
        if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
            switch ($_POST['consulta']) {
                case 'ciudades':
                    $listado = ListaCiudades();
                    echo json_encode($listado); //Aqui es donde no me imprime
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}



?>
```

Gracias por vuestra colaboracion

Comment: ¿Ya hiciste un `var_dump($listado)` a ver que te devuelve?

Comment: si lo he realizado, imprime el array normal

Comment: hasta imprimí el tamaño del array y me devuelve 49

Comment: ¿Ya probaste removiendo la línea `break`?

Comment: Lo probaré, ya te cuento

Comment: No funciona quitar esa linea

Comment: prueba con `echo json_encode(array($listado))`

Answer (score 0):

Listo muchachos, lo he conseguido, este es el código:

```
<?php

require "../model/Ciudad.php";

$_POST = $_GET;

function ListaCiudades(){
    $ciudad = new Ciudad();
    $ciudades = $ciudad->Select_Ciudaddes();
    $array_return = array();

    if($ciudades != null){
        foreach ($ciudades as $ciudad) {

            $arr = array("id_ciudad" => utf8_encode($ciudad['PK_ID_CIUDAD']), 
                         "nombre" => utf8_encode($ciudad['NOMBRE']));
            array_push($array_return, $arr);
        }
    }

    return $array_return;
    // var_dump(json_encode($array_return, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}

/*Identificación del típo de consulta a realizar*/
if(isset($_POST['tipo'])){
    if($_POST['tipo'] == 'consulta'){
        if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
            switch ($_POST['consulta']) {
                case 'ciudades':
                    $listado = ListaCiudades();
                    echo json_encode($listado);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

El problema era por el juego de caracteres, lo solucioné poniendo el utf8_encode cuando guardo a cada array. Gracias por su ayuda fue muy util!

Comment: Por favor márcalo como solucionado, haciendo clic en el símbolo de cotejo, a la izquierda.

Comment: @aldanux ¿Porque es su propia respuesta?

Comment: @aldanux Algo más aprendido, gracias. :)